# Applying combine function over dataframe and saving as a single list/dataframe

Tags: r, combn

I am trying to create a network. I have a dataframe:

. . v1  .v2  .v3
1/  .1 ...  2.... 3

2/  .3 ...  4 ..  7

3/. 6   ...11 . 9

I wish to find all possible combinations within each row. For example, the 1st row has the values 1, 2, 3 so the result would be (1, 2) (1, 3) (2, 3). Then I would go on to find the combinations between values in only the second row 3, 4, 7 returning (3, 4) (3, 7) (4, 7).

Now I wish to do this function by row and then combine all the results to have an edge list of sorts to create the network out of.

I have tried for couple hours iterations of for functions, apply, and combn but I cant seem to get it to work.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this?

Finally, I am relatively new to R. Is there a way I should break it down or do something step by step to solve? I would really appreciate if you could use simple functions like apply, for loops, and stuff rather than odd specific functions. That way I can look over your ideas and learn from them so I can apply them to other problems later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were probably very close
(though you should post the code of your attempt in the future,
and also use something like `dput` for your data).

The problem of using `apply` is that it will try to simplify automatically
(to something like a single vector or matrix),
and since `combn` returns matrices,
you definitely don't want simplification.
You should use `lapply` when you have cases like these:

```
lapply(1L:nrow(your_data_frame), function(i) { combn(your_data_frame[i,], m=2L) })
```

Comment: That seems to work. The list that is returned is formatted into pairs. In the original code, I have 0's that I would like to remove. If the list generated from the combination lapply function has a pair that has a zero I would like to remove it. Would you happen to know of a way to do this. My current approach is converting all the zero's to NAs and trying to do another apply/lapply function to remove all the NAs. The issue I am having is that R seems to remove only the NA's rather than the entire pair. Any ideas? Anyways thanks for your help!

Comment: @EthanHunt If this answer was helpful to you, please upvote it.  If it answered your question,  please accept it as a correct answer. You might take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)